# I want to separate data and time from a DBStamp Data type in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing this query in ALM query Builder which is a PL/SQL database.
I have a field where the time is of the format `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"`.

I basically want to separate `Date` and `Time` and use `Lead` or `Lag` function to calculate `TIME` difference between the rows following it.

Or can we do this without separating date and time?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "PL/SQL database". It's an Oracle database. And why do you want a stored procedure for this?

Comment: Does the field have a `DATE` type or a `CHAR` type that happens to have the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`? Hopefully the former.

Comment: @MT0 - The datatype is DBTimeStamp

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - with ALM you can know the defect status and time at which it was moved in a particular state ( initiated, assigned or resolved). I want to calculate the time difference between those states. How much delay was there and all that.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle 11g Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( time ) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-12-20 00:00:00.0000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-12-21 00:00:00.0000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-12-21 03:20:00.0000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-12-21 03:20:01.2300' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT time,
       LAG( time ) OVER ( ORDER BY time ) AS prev_time,
       time - LAG( time ) OVER ( ORDER BY time ) AS difference
FROM   table_name;
```

**Results**:

```
TIME               PREV_TIME          DIFFERENCE
------------------ ------------------ -----------
20-DEC-15 00.00.00                                
21-DEC-15 00.00.00 20-DEC-15 00.00.00 1 0:0:0.0   
21-DEC-15 03.20.00 21-DEC-15 00.00.00 0 3:20:0.0  
21-DEC-15 03.20.01 21-DEC-15 03.20.00 0 0:0:1.23
```